# MAMP and Yosemite PDO Exception Driver Issue

Tags: mamp, osx-yosemite

I installed Yosemite and now when I use MAMP I receive this Fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CRUD/pdo.php:3 Stack trace: #0     
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CRUD/pdo.php(3): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'fred', 
'zap') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CRUD/index.php(2): require_once('/Applications/M...') 
#2 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CRUD/pdo.php on line 3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to fix it:

- Start MAMP
- On the top left, go to "MAMP" -> "Preferences"
- Go to the "PHP" tab
- Tick PHP 5.5.17 (or whatever you have) instead of the one which is ticked by default (5.6.1 -> 5.5.17 with he latest version of MAMP)

Comment: I found (with Mamp Pro 3.0.6, which ships with PHP 5.5.14) that I needed to enable network access to MySQL -- which I don't normally have switched on during local development (since socket is fine). Once done, PDO worked fine.